# What is the runtime of the stack implemented as list in python (and why)?

Tags: python, data-structures, stack

I am studying the stack data structure and keep reading that the pop() operation is O(n) time when implemented as a list. I am confused because it seems like you can use list.append() and then list.pop(), which to my understanding are both O(1) complexity, so despite the dynamic array resizing isn't the amortized runtime still linear?

My second confusion is about the runtime of the dynamic array resizing. To my understanding copying the elements to the new list is O(n) time. Does the process of allocating new memory take time in addition to the process of copying the contents of list, or are those the same process?

Comment: *which to my understanding are both O(1) complexity* - well not in the general case. for an arbitrary index `i`, the operation `l.pop(i)` is O(n) on average, where `n = len(l)`. For `i = len(l) - 1` (the last element) of course it's O(1).

Comment: don't confuse python `list` with `linked list`, a python `list` is a `vector` or `array` in other languages, a continuous block of data with a `size` and `capacity` property